# get all ADcontroller of another domain

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm stuck in a stupid problem that I can't figure out how to solve.
I need to get all domain controllers of a trusted domain.

With this piece of code I get all DC in the current domain `Get-ADDomainController -Filter *`
With this I get one DC from target domain `Get-ADDomainController -domain MyTrustedDomain -Discover`
But how can I get all DC in target domain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way without using AD module:

```
$a = new-object 'System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.DirectoryContext'("domain", "other.domain.local" )
[System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.DomainController]::FindAll($a)
```

You need to be an 'authenticated user' in the remote domain or add username and password parameter to the `DirectoryContext` object

Comment: is there a similar way to get servers from that domain without using AD module? something like `[System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.AnyComputer]::FindAll($a)`

Answer (score 7):

Can't test this due to lack of AD, but you could try the `-Server` option with the FQDN of the trusted domain:

```
Get-ADDomainController -Filter * -Server trusted.example.com
```

Answer (score 1):

I've come across the same problem as I work regularly with multiple domains.  I was hoping for a more elegant solution, but so far the best I've come up with is to take your work one step further.

if `Get-ADDomainController -domain MyTrustedDomain -Discover` gives you one server in the target domain, you can feed that to the -server parameter to query that one DC.  You do need to provide credentials to query a DC from a different domain than your login session if a trust **DOES NOT** exist (in a trust, the trusting domain considers you to be 'authenticated').

```
$targetdcname = (Get-ADDomainController -DomainName <MyTrustedDomain> -Discover).hostname
Get-ADDomainController -Filter * `
  -Server $targetdcname `
  -Credential (Get-Credential MyTrustedDomain\username) | ft HostName
```

or

```
Get-ADDomainController -Filter * `
  -Server $((Get-ADDomainController -DomainName  <MyTrustedDomain> -Discover).hostname) `
  -Credential (Get-Credential MyTrustedDomain\username) | ft HostName
```

If you do this sort of thing alot, you can always store your credentials in a variable for reuse, `$cred = Get-Credential MyTrustedDomain\username)` and save the repeated prompts.  The password is stored as a System.Security.SecureString and will be secure as long as you keep it within your session.

Until the Get-ADDomainController cmdlet is updated to allow both the -filter parameter AND the Domainname parameter, we're stuck with a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

This command will list all domain controllers in the forest for each domain

```
(get-adforest).domains |%{get-addomaincontrollers -filter * -server $_}
```

Comment: This implies both domains are in the same forest, not simply that they are both trusting.  Plus, this will give you domain controllers from every domain that is in the forest, and since your depending on the query against the domain name itself, this code has a possible 'single point of failure' based on if the server returned by DNS in the domain look up (the $_ value here is the domain name, not a server name), is actually online.

Answer (score 0):

from: help get-addomaincontroller -examples

This should list all DCs in your domain

-------------------------- EXAMPLE 12 --------------------------

```
C:\PS>Get-ADDomainController -Filter  { isGlobalCatalog -eq $true -and Site -eq "Default-First-Site-Name" }


Get all global catalogs in a given site.
```

Comment: Actually, this lists all DC's that are global catalogs within your site, not the domain.  And as the question asked for DC's in a trusted domain, this response doesn't really answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
Get-ADDomain -Identity <DOMAIN NAME> | select -ExpandProperty ReplicaDirectoryServers
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I used

```
cls

$domains = (Get-ADForest).Domains;

foreach ($domain in $domains)

{

Write-Host $domain
(Get-ADDomain -Identity $domain | select -ExpandProperty ReplicaDirectoryServers).Count;
Write-Host "";
$totalCount = $totalCount + (Get-ADDomain -Identity $domain | select -ExpandProperty ReplicaDirectoryServers).Count;
}

Write-Host "Total domain controller count is: "$totalCount
```

Comment: Why do the expensive domain look up twice to get the same information?
Save the value from the first domain lookup, and then add it to $TotalCount instead of making two calls to "Get-ADDomain".

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the start, here's what I came up with. Then I feed it to a SharePoint list.

```
get-adtrust -Filter * | Select-object Name, Domain,ipv4Address, OperatingSystem, Site, HostName, OperatingSystemVersion | ForEach-Object{Get-ADDomainController -Filter * -Server $_.Name}
```

Answer (score 0):

Get-ADDomainController -filter * | FT

Can we remove the FQDN and only keep the host name.

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes Powershell adds complexity, just open a cmd prompt and enter

*C:\Windows\System32\nltest.exe /dclist:[trusted domain]*

Of course, replace [trusted domain] with the name of the domain whose DC's you want.

Comment: 1:  This would required elevated credentials.  an NSLOOKUP <DomainName> would give the list, if that was all you needed.
2.  This could give you pages of information that you would then need to parse thru.  This is not a reasonable solution.